# Joomla error Class 'JModelLegacy' not found

Tags: php, joomla

When I am using a specific module in my Joomla website, I am getting this error

```
 Class 'JModelLegacy' not found in sitename/modules/mod_map/helper.php on line 8
```

Helper file includes this code:

```
<?php

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

jimport('joomla.application.component.model');
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_SITE.'/components/com_content/models');

class mod_mapHelper{

    public function getPlace($params){

        $things = Array();

        $things['name'] = $params->get('placeName');
        $things['lat'] = $params->get('latitude');
        $things['long'] = $params->get('longitude');
        $things['zoom'] = $params->get('zoom');

        return $things;

    }
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: what version of Joomla are you using?

Comment: Did you write this module? Can you add the PHP from the modules `mod_modulename.php` file so we can help?

Comment: What are you using the content model for and why are you using it where you are?

Comment: @Lodder the joomla version is 1.7

Comment: @Takis - and why are you using Joomla 1.7? Get yourself upgraded to 2.5 or even better (not not a necessity), 3.2. I can't stress how silly it is to be using an old version of Joomla which not only poses security issues, but is not longer supported!!

Comment: @Lodder I know that isues Lodder but this isnt a live site. i only use it for intranet purposes and i cant update it to 2.5 version because some components doesnt work on that version. As you can guess there are a lot of modificated modules, templates, components etc

Comment: So is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I believe `JModelLegacy` was added into Joomla 2.5 (not sure on the exact version) therefore Joomla 1.7 does not support this.

So you need to simply change `JModelLegacy::addIncludePath` to `JModel::addIncludePath`